# Problems w/ dual-booting Debian alongside Windows 10

Tags: debian, dual-boot

I installed a Debian image onto a bootable usb and booted it. Then I began installing via the graphical installer. I've tried five plus times. When I am done installing, my computer boots straight to Windows. What is going on? I have an Asus q500a if that helps.